# This site can’t be reached after installing WSL2 and apache2

Tags: windows-10, apache2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I updated my WSL1 to WSL2 and install

> ubuntu 20.04,
> Apache2 and
> php8

Now visiting localhost will display the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

Next I create a `conf` file on `/etc/apache2/sites-available/items.test.conf` containing

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName items.test

    ServerAdmin admin@items.test
    DocumentRoot /mnt/c/www/path/to/public

    <Directory /mnt/c/www/path/to/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

run `sudo a2ensite items.test.conf` and `sudo service apache2 reload`. Next open `host` with notepad with administrator, and added `127.0.0.1 items.test`

Visiting the site locally `items.test` give me this message

> This site can’t be reached

What am I missing in this, spend 24hrs tweaking and no luck

Answer (score 4):

After digging another few hours I found the answer, update host file with such a like:

```
127.0.0.1 test.tld
::1 test.tld
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4347